# How can I get the District or City name by using google map api in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

In Bangladesh there are 65 Districts (ex: Dhaka, Chittagong etc). I want to add a feature in my Android App. After pressing the particular button user get his District name in a TextView.

We can easily mark the current location of user in Google map. But I need the District name as a String.

How can it be possible?
Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Geocoder object, you can call the getFromLocation(double, double, int) method. It will return a list of Address objects that have a method getLocality().

```
  Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
  List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
   Log.e("District",addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```